# JavaScript RegExp: All matches of a given format up until pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this dummy input data:

`john: buys beer
sam: eats bananas
*** DIVIDER
irrelevant actions
luis: walking`

And the `regex` that captures person's actions: `/^[\S]*:.*/gm`

I need to modify it so that it includes only actions that were up to a given pattern (`*** DIVIDER`) further down the text.

I thought I might use e.g. `/^[\S]*:.*(?=[\S]*\sDIVIDER)/gm` but it's not working for some reason.

I setup a [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/8A89iH/1) to play

Comment: One way is split on the divider first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking among lines, you need to use `[\s\S]*?` in positive lookahead. However, talking performance wise, it's not a good practice. A fast way to achieve it is matching all lines following pattern `\S+:.*` then look if they are followed by the divider:

```
^(?:[^:\s]+:.*\s+)+(?=.*?DIVIDER)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/VR24MA/2)

```js
var s = `john: buys beer
sam: eats bananas
*** DIVIDER
irrelevant actions
luis: walking
john: buys beer`;

console.log(s.match(/^(?:[^:\s]+:.*\s+)+(?=.*?DIVIDER)/gm));
```

Comment: thanks this seems to solve the issue. However not sure why my original lookahead `(?=[\S]*\sDIVIDER)` was not working. Guess I am understanding the lookahead wrong. And by the way what is `/s` flag? It doesn't belong to the `flags` list @ MDN

Comment: Dot `.` in a regex doesn't go beyond a single line, neither does `\S*\s`. Latter could go for one more line but not multiple lines. To go beyond lines you need `[\s\S]*?` or `.` with `s` (`DOTALL`) flag in most flavors. I forgot to mention JS lacks support for `s` flag, even though it's proposed for ES2018. My fault.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful!

Comment: Hrm this is weird. I tried running your snippet and the output of the `match` method is an array which consists of 1 element, while there should be 2 of them O_O

Comment: @knitevision It's possible to modify regex to have each line in a separate array value but it would be much more faster if you split output by `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving your problem is to fully use the power of regular expressions to simplify javascript code as well as avoiding possible format errors (*e.g. trailing spaces, empty lines, missing fields*). Also it does not use the `s` flag missing in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

### Regexp

I ended up with the following regex:

`^\s*([^:]*):\s*([^\n]*)(?:\n[^\n]*DIVIDER[^\n]*\n[^\n]*)?$`

> Regex101 available [here](https://regex101.com/r/2YlZNO/5)

### Capturing groups

For each line, the regex will output 2 matching groups:

- the first containing the trimmed user
- the second containing the trimmed action

### Javascript

In order for javascript to extract all matching groups (*i.e. flag `g`*), you must execute the regex while the data matches.

```js
// 1. init data
var regex  = /^\s*([^:]*):\s*([^\n]*)(?:\n[^\n]*DIVIDER[^\n]*\n[^\n]*)?$/gm;
var output = [];
var input  = `user1: buys beer
              user 2: eats bananas
              *** DIVIDER
              irrelevant actions
              user-3:     walking

                 user 4: buys beer
              user5:eats bananas
              *** DIVIDER
              irrelevant actions
              usr6: walking
              : eats bananas
              user7:`;

// 2. iterate over matches
while( match = regex.exec(input) )
   output.push({user: match[1], action: match[2]})
   
// 3. do stuff with result
console.log(output)
```

### Benefits

The regex syntax lets you avoid (in this example) some possible errors:

- missing user
- missing action
- empty lines
- space characters (*i.e. space, tab*) before the user name
- space characters before the action value

Also, the code for extracting data takes only 2 lines (*see code below*).

### Regex breakthrough

- `\s*` ignore possible space characters before **user**

  - `([^:]*)` match **user** (any character except `:`)
  - `:`  the separator : between **user** and **action**
  - `\s*` ignore possible space characters before **action**
  - `([^\n]*)` match **action** until the end of the line
- `(?:` non-capturing group containing the DIVIDER section

  - `\n` check next line
  - `[^\n]*DIVIDER` continue until "*DIVIDER*" reached
  - `[^\n]*\n` ignore end of DIVIDER line
  - `[^\n]*`   ignore next line
- `)?` this group is optional

Hope it helped !